# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session. Spring + Hibernate + HSQLDB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have some problems with Spring + Hibernate + HSQLDB configuration.
I receive:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
org.siwoz.dao.model.Person_$$_javassist_0.toString(Person_$$_javassist_0.java)
org.siwoz.controller.IndexController.index(IndexController.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I've tried to use OpenSessionInViewInterceptor (for hibernate 3), but then i have:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource must not be null
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource must not be null
org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.unwrapResourceIfNecessary(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:62)
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.hasResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:124)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.preHandle(OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.java:143)
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.preHandle(WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.java:54)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:891)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Here is my cfg file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:db/db.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "my_package_name" })
public class PersistenceConfig {

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Bean
public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
    sessionFactory
            .setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "my_package_name" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    try {
        sessionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() {
    return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory().getObject());
}

@Bean
public DataSource restDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
}

@Bean
public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
    return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
}

Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8249579451140862991L;
        {
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.pool_size",
                    env.getProperty("hibernate.conn.pool"));
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                    env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                    env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
            setProperty(
                    "hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers",
                    env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers",
                    env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"));
        }
    };
}
}
```

I have an abstract repository, here is the piece of code:

```
public abstract class AbstractRepository<T> {

@Autowired
protected HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

public abstract T getById(long id);
}
```

And here is my PersonRepository:

```
@Repository("personRepository")
public class PersonRepository extends AbstractRepository<Person> {

@Override
     public Person getById(long id) {
    return hibernateTemplate.load(Person.class, id);
}
```

I'm using only annotation config (no xmls) and loading my db scheme and data from *.sql files - I can see the scheme and data in hsql manager.
 Exceptions occur when I invoke getById(). I also checked my entity in sessionFactory.getObject().getAllClassMetadata()- its loaded.

Spring - 3.1
Hibernate - 3.6.10.Final
Tomcat - 7
HSQLDB - 2.3.2
I think there is a stupid mistake, but I cannot see it.
Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
I noticed strange errors in my Tomcat console:

```
[ERROR] [localhost-startStop-1 06:06:19] (SchemaExport.java:create:386) Unsucces
sful: create table `Address` (`id` bigint not null auto_increment, `city` varcha
r(255), `street` varchar(255), primary key (`id`))
[ERROR] [localhost-startStop-1 06:06:19] (SchemaExport.java:create:387) unexpect
ed token:  required: (
[ERROR] [localhost-startStop-1 06:06:19] (SchemaExport.java:create:386) Unsucces
sful: create table `Person` (`id` bigint not null auto_increment, `name` varchar
(255), `pass` varchar(255), `pesel` varchar(255), `surname` varchar(255), primar
y key (`id`))
[ERROR] [localhost-startStop-1 06:06:19] (SchemaExport.java:create:387) unexpect
ed token:  required: (
[ERROR] [localhost-startStop-1 06:06:19] (SchemaExport.java:create:386) Unsucces
sful: create table `Address` (`id` bigint not null auto_increment, `city` varcha
r(255), `street` varchar(255), primary key (`id`))
[ERROR] [localhost-startStop-1 06:06:19] (SchemaExport.java:create:387) unexpect
ed token:  required: (
[ERROR] [localhost-startStop-1 06:06:19] (SchemaExport.java:create:386) Unsucces
sful: create table `Person` (`id` bigint not null auto_increment, `name` varchar
(255), `pass` varchar(255), `pesel` varchar(255), `surname` varchar(255), primar
y key (`id`))
[ERROR] [localhost-startStop-1 06:06:19] (SchemaExport.java:create:387) unexpect
ed token:  required: (
```

I don't know where the error could be, I'm also adding piece of db_scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE Address (
id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY primary key,
city varchar(64),
street varchar(64)
);
```

In hsqldb gui there are no errors, when I'm deleting/adding scheme and data.

Comment: Try `get` instead of `load`, the latter always creates a proxy instead of going to the database. It will only go to the database when you want to access properties of the actual underlying record. Also you shouldn't use `HibernateTemplate` anymore but rather a plain `SessionFactory`, use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession` to get access to the underlying session. (This will also tell when you don't have a proper transaction setup).

Comment: Yes, I read about HibernateTemplate, I just wanted to try every possible solution :) Ok, I did what you said:
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
return (Person) session.get(Person.class, 1L);
and have following exceptions: http://pastebin.com/sFZiygEp

Comment: Apparently your mapping configuration is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `@Transactional` annotation

Try something like this:

```
@Repository("personRepository")
@Transactional
public class PersonRepository extends AbstractRepository<Person> {

@Override
     public Person getById(long id) {
    return hibernateTemplate.load(Person.class, id);
}
```

I hope this can help
Angelo

Comment: I'm sory didn't mention that earlier - I'm using @Transactional at Service level.
My chain of requests looks like that:
JSP(user enters page) - Controller - PersonService - PersonRepository.

Thanks for quick answer anyway (I tried it anyway, but the result was the same).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers.
Unfortunately I haven't find any solution to my problem.
I created most simple entity with only id, and problem was the same.
I used different database - MySQL - and everything is fine now.

Comment: may you post your mappings, your models and your hibernate configuration?